# Vector Plane Equation

Tags: vectors

Given 3 points:
$A (1,2,3)
B (1,1,2)
C (2,1,2)$

I have calculated the equation of the vector plane to be $z-y=1$.

However, I do not understand how the equation of the plane can be independent of $x$ when $x$ is clearly changing in the coordinates above. I feel I am missing something crucial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the same reason as, in the $(x,y)$-plane, a horizontal line has equation $y=\text{constant}$, which is independent of $x$.

Comment: This is no different in principle from the equation $z=0$ of the $x$-$y$ plane. Would this be less troubling to you if you made the coefficient of $x$ explicit: $0x-y+z=1$?

Comment: This makes sense now, thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You determined (correctly) that the plane that contains $A$, $B$, and $C$ is the plane $z-y=1$. What this means is that the points of the plane are all the points of the form $(x,y,y+1)$. As you can see, $x$ can, in fact, take *any* value you want. So, the fact that $A$, $B$, and $C$ don't have all the same first coordinate is not a problem.